# tweening library in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flare3d

I am looking for a **tweening library for Flex.**
But what I need:

1) it uses (x,y,z) and not only (x,y)

2) It juist makes calculs and is not associated with a movie clip: the goal is to use it for a 3D library (Flare3D) to make smooth camera movement. So I will manually update the camera position according to the (x,y,z)

I tried tweelite but none of these 2 requirements are filled.

Comment: Many would say that "StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine" so I'm not sure how appropriate this question is. It seems to me that a Tweening Library that doesn't move things is not a Tweening library; so I'm not sure what you need. Maybe some type of mathematics library?  Perhaps you should re-write this question to explain what you need; what you've tried; and why that attempt didn't work.

Comment: Since you're already using the Flex framework have you considered/tried the built in animation classes http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/04/22/creating-a-simple-property-animation-in-flex-4/ Also as an aside I've recently been using "actuate" a library I found on Google code that is good with performance and easy to use http://code.google.com/p/actuate/

Answer (score 1):

Why isn't TweenLite suitable? It animates any properties you like, not just x/y.

btw, avoid the Flex tweening engine - it stinks.

Comment: This isn't really an answer and probably shouldn't have been posted as such.  If you have questions; or other opinions; usually posting a comment is considered appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to use TweenLite with Flare3D to generate a Vertex based animation.
http://wiki.flare3d.com/index.php?title=Tweened_Vertex_Spheres

Also, you can find more info in Flare3D Forum. For example:
http://www.flare3d.com/support/index.php?topic=1957.msg16605#msg16605